# Ajax http request loads previouse images into carousal when i make new request

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on a mobile App using javascript (PhoneGap with Wordpress Rest API for wooCommerce Multivendor.

My code is written to collect the product ID and load the Images into a carousel.

**The Problem**
When I click on any product, it loads the image, if I go back and click on a new product it loads the image of the new one and the previous one I loaded into the carousel.

I have been battling with it since morning. Any suggestion that can be of help will be appreciated

**HTML**

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                          <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img id="mainImage" src="" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                            </div>
                        <div id="otherImgagesHere">

                        </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
var tokenDetails = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxwENs';

  function loadDetail(lnk){
    var selProductId = lnk.getAttribute('value');

  var getProductDetails = new XMLHttpRequest();
  getProductDetails.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

          var authJsonGetProductDetails = JSON.parse(getProductDetails.responseText);
          document.getElementById('productDetailName').innerHTML = authJsonGetProductDetails.name;
          document.getElementById('productDetailTitle').innerHTML = authJsonGetProductDetails.name;
          document.getElementById('productDetailPrice').innerHTML = authJsonGetProductDetails.price;
          document.getElementById('productDetailShort_description').innerHTML = authJsonGetProductDetails.short_description;


          var mainImageName = authJsonGetProductDetails.images[0].src;
          console.log(mainImageName);

          document.getElementById("mainImage").src = mainImageName;

          var mainImageDisplayCode = '<img src="'+mainImageName+'" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">';
           console.log(mainImageDisplayCode);
           document.getElementById('mainImage').innerHTML = mainImageDisplayCode;

         // document.getElementById("mainImage").setAttribute("src", authJsonGetProductDetails.images[0].src); 
          //console.log(authJsonGetProductDetails.images[x].src);

         for(var x=0; x <  authJsonGetProductDetails.images.length; x++) {
           var imageLink = authJsonGetProductDetails.images[x].src;
           var otherImageDisplayCode = '<div  class="carousel-item">'+
                                          '<img src="'+imageLink+'"  alt="...">'+
                                        '</div>'; 
          console.log(otherImageDisplayCode);           
           document.getElementById('otherImgagesHere').innerHTML += otherImageDisplayCode;
         }


          location.replace("#productDetails");

    }
  };
getProductDetails.open("GET", "<base_url>/wp-json/wcfmmp/v1/products/"+selProductId, true);
getProductDetails.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
getProductDetails.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + tokenDetails);
getProductDetails.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
getProductDetails.send();




  }
```

Comment: If there are any screenshots  might make better sense, based on what you said. Do you try to "clean" your carousel before loading the new one if you intend to have only one product?

Answer (score 0):

The bad line of code is inside your for loop at the end where you're adding the HTML elements:

```
document.getElementById('otherImgagesHere').innerHTML += otherImageDisplayCode;
```

You are using += so it will always append to what was there previously. I would recommend adding

`document.getElementById('otherImgagesHere').innerHTML = ""`

just above your for loop to see if that helps